# Adding login of a pc on the network - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, windows, logins, network

I have a small office network and I am trying to add new logins for the other PCs on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 (all computers are Windows 7).

I cannot seem to find the other machines when going to: Server name>Security>Logins-new>Login-name

I can only see my pc.

My pc is the also the server in the office and can share the network drives with the other computers.

How do I add the other computers as new logins?

Do I have to create a different SQL connection? How?

[image: A screenshot]

Comment: Are all PC's in the same workgroup? Could you use SQL Server authentication?

Comment: Hi McNets, yes I have just checked and all the pcs are in the same workgroup. If I connect authenticating with SQL Server authentication with the default profile (sa) I have the same problem. No other computer is showing up. I can see the other pcs in "Network" and I could set some of my folders as network drives. I am not sure if there is any security option to allow the other PCs to be added as new logins...

Comment: You can set up a SQL Server login for each user.

Comment: Hi McNets, by setting a new SQL Server login the other pcs can connect but I cannot still see them on the new machine. Is there any way for me to add them with new login> Windows authentication? I cannot see the other PCs from my main machine in "location".

Comment: And can you see this machines in File Explorer\Network?. Network discovery should be turned on. I'm sorry but I can check it now.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be5014e5-5156-43db-8ea3-e28bc68b1fca/how-to-create-sql-server-login-for-workgroup-computer?forum=sqlsecurity